# How to return a chosen value with an error Mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have this code I want to test :

```
my_function():
   try:
        return foo()
    except SQLAlchemyError as db_error:
        return [db_error, 400]
```

To raise an error, I did this in my test:

```
@patch("my_file.foo")
def test_my_function(foo):
    foo.side_effect = SQLAlchemyError(Mock())

    assert my_function() == I dont know :(
```

The problem there is that `my_function` return `[SQLAlchemyError(<Mock id='140357971250720'>), 400]` so even if I turn it into a string, the id will change at every run.

Comment: Just turn it into a string, but remove the digits of the ID.

Comment: Isn't that enough for your test? You can simply compare your Mock to the Mock returned to verify the function does its work. You will have to store the Mock though.

Comment: You don't need a second mock. `foo.side_effect = SQLAlchemyError("foo")`.  `my_function` is going to return a list containing that exception and `400`; do with it as you need.

Comment: @quamrana To remove the id, I would had to knew it, and if I knew it, I would be able to test the equality

Comment: @KlausD. It worked ! But chepner's found the "real" problem of my code. Thank you though.

Comment: @chepner That is the problem, well played.

Comment: Why would you need to know the the value of the ID? You only need to know where it is in the string.

Comment: @quamrana And how do I remove it then ? If what you want is to remove everything after the word "id" occur, it would be a little messy, no ?

Comment: Its possible to write a function to remove everything inside the `'`s from the string representation of a MagicMock object.